# Update database from inserted table fields

Tags: php, html

I have made a table with editable fields and i have to add functionality to the update button. I have looked up many posts but cant seem to figure out how it works.

Heres what i have at this moment:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['update'])) {

  $query = mysql_query("UPDATE iekartas SET
iernosauk='$Ierices_Nosaukums', tips='$Tips', razotajs='$Razotajs',
izgatdat='$Izgatavosanas_datums', adrese='$Adrese' where id='$Iekartas_ID'", $connection);
}
$query = mysql_query("select * from iekartas", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<b><a href='iekartas.php?update={$row['Iekartas_ID']}'>{$row['Ierices_Nosaukums']}</a></b>";
echo "<br />";

}
?>

<tr>
    <form action="ierices.php" method="post">
        <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['Iekartas_ID'] ?>" name="id[]"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="iernosauk" value=" <?php echo $row["Ierices_Nosaukums"]; ?>"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="tips" value=" <?php echo $row["Tips"]; ?>"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="razotajs" value=" <?php echo $row["Razotajs"]; ?>"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="izgatdat" value=" <?php echo $row["Izgatavosanas_datums"]; ?>"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="adrese" value=" <?php echo $row["Adrese"]; ?>"></td>
        <td> <input type="hidden" name="id" value=" <?php echo $row["Iekartas_ID"]; ?>"></td>

<?php
    $i++;
}
?>

        <button type="button" action="update.php" name="updatedb" class="btn btn-danger" id="updatedb" value=update>Atjaunot</button>
</tr>
    </form>
```

Comment: Pass fields to server, on server run `UPDATE` query.

Comment: The html tag nesting is broken in your code. `<form>` and `<tr>` are not properly nested with their respective closing tags.

Comment: @Fabian Schöner 17  Thanks, didnt see that one

Comment: After editing your HTML it's wrong and we lack a part : 1/ You close your `</tr>` before closing the `</form>`, 2/ where is the beginning of the php part?

Answer (score 1):

`Button` is client side so your "update.php" won't be triggered when you click on button. What you have to do is change your button type to `submit` so your form will actually send a POST request when you click on the button and it will call the action on the form (ierices.php)

```
<form action="ierices.php" method="post">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="updatedb">Atjaunot</button>
</form
```

Comment: Oh, okay. But my query still doesnt update anything. Maybe u can check it out. i updated my post with it.